# python: increase a variable as another decreases

Tags: python, variables

I'm making a game where I have a force field. I need the force towards the source to increase as I get closer. I have a code that gets the distance between the player and the source and I want to set the strength of the force as the distance between the objects. However, as I get closer to the source, the distance decreases and so does the strength of the force. Is it possible to have another variable that somehow goes opposite of the distance so that as distance decreases, it increases?

Comment: What kind of behavior do you expect? You could use a constant force. Or `1/r`.

Comment: To fully control the force consider something like `constant1/(constant2 +r)`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following structure:

```
import math

force_constant = 100 #linearly increases the force applied to the player
max_pull_constant = 1 #fractionally decreases the maximum force applied to the player
point_source = [0,0,0]
point_player = [0,10,0]

def radius (point_player, point_source):
    return_value_vector = [(p-s)**2 for p, s in zip(point_player, point_source)]
    return_value_scalar = math.sqrt(sum(return_value_vector))
    return return_value_scalar

def pulling_force(point_player, point_source):
    return_value_scalar = force_constant/(max_pull_constant + radius(point_player, point_source))

def pulling_force_vector(point_player, point_source):
    return_radius = radius(point_player, point_source)
    return_vector = [(p-s)/return_radius for p, s in zip(point_player, point_source)]
    return_force = pulling_force(point_player, point_source)
    return_value_force_vector = [return_force*v for v in return_vector]
    return return_value_force_vector

#Main program here
#Call pulling_force(player_location, source_location) to get the force from the force field
```

This structure should be what you are looking for, I wrote it assuming three dimensions, edit as needed. Enjoy!